# Решение произвольного выражения

Tags: c#, .net, visual-basic, интерпретатор

Как реализовать решение выражения (со скобками и функциями (*`Sin()`*...)), которое вводит пользователь с клавиатуры.

- Писать свой интерпретатор выражений не подходит
- Программа должна работать и на ПК **без** MS Office (можно как-то использовать Excel для этих целей)

> Где-то слышал, что можно как-то использовать **`JScript`**

Comment: Извините, а вопрос-то какой?

Comment: Надо скачать соответствующий калькулятор и все, и офис не нужен и писать ничего не надо. В чем вопрос-то заключается? Как-то можно использовать и не только JScript. Вы под интерпретатор и парсер выражений подразумеваете одно и то же? 

Уточните какую задачу и с какими условиями вам надо решить.

Comment: @Raskilas, дано: строка вида: "12*25*(Sin(30)+1)" или "2+2", в общем, математическое выражение.

Задача: найти ответ у обоих выражений, т. е. выполнить все действия, соблюдая их порядок. Что тут не понятного?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[eval в С#](http://forum.codenet.ru/q26577/eval+%D0%B2+%D0%A1%23).

> Как воспользоватся функцией eval из javascript или каким-то ее аналогом в С#.